# Can't get mahout itemsimilarity result with preferences (booleanValue=false)

Tags: mahout, collaborative-filtering, mahout-recommender

I'm trying to create get itemismilarity using mahout. The problem is that I do get few similarities in output.

Here are my input data characteristics:

- 15.910.847 total count of preferences
- 4.047.745 distinct users
- 773.015 distinct items
  I've built the distribution of users and prefereces

The first column is count of distinct users

The second column is count of preferences per users. I do have 2.221.760 uses which have only one preference, for example.

> ```
> 2221760   1
> 688258    2
> 322497    3
> 192003    4
> 122446    5
> 87033 6
> 63733 7
> 49556 8
> 39090 9
> 31637 10
> 25634 11
> ```

Here are my input settings:

```
similarityClassname=SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION
maxSimilaritiesPerItem=100000
minPrefsPerUser=0

booleanData=false
threshold=0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Column 1 should be Mahout user ID, from 0 thru number of users - 1
Column 2 should be Mahout item ID, from 0 to number of items - 1 You can't just count preferences you want to record each item that the user showed some preference for
Column 3 is the strength of preference, like a rating

IDs are like row and column numbers in a matrix or table 0,0 is user 0 item 0, the value is the rating.

You must translate your IDs into Mahout IDs then back again into your ids when reading the results of itemsimilarity.

Comment: Hi :) I got your response in mahout user group. I'm using org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob and I can't find requirement for mapping numerical user and item ids to range [0..qtty_of_users], [0..qtty_of_items] before feeding preference data to mahout.... The same for org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob where I can get itemSimilarityMatrix

Comment: And yet it is true.  I'll write up a wiki page describing this. We just rewrote the Wiki for 0.9 release and is was missed.

Comment: Great, going to try and report.

Comment: didn't help. I've used apache pig Rank function to give 1..N id for each distinct user_id and 1..M for each distinct item_id. I did feed ItemSimilarityJob with dataset, where user_id in [1..N], item_id [1..M], preference: 1.0 or 2.0, output result is pretty the same 16*10^6 preferences from 4*10^6 users for 7*10^5 items give only 10^3 similarities for 10 items... What do I do wrong? Does input dataset should be ordered by item/users id?

Answer (score 0):

> didn't help. I've used apache pig Rank function to give 1..N id for each distinct user_id and 1..M for each distinct item_id. I did feed ItemSimilarityJob with dataset, where user_id in [1..N], item_id [1..M], preference: 1.0 or 2.0, output result is pretty the same 16*10^6 preferences from 4*10^6 users for 7*10^5 items give only 10^3 similarities for 10 items... What do I do wrong? Does input dataset should be ordered by item/users id? –  Sergey Jul 27 at 20:46

It is because Mahout taste implementations accept ints as input for user_ids. If you supply anything that overflows MAX.int value, it will rollover to a minimum, which means it wont get added as a unique user.

You could perhaps Hash your user_id if it exceeds MAX.int value before you feed it to Mahout. Or you could have a alpha-numeric id and then user the ID-Migrator class for user_id input.

Answer (score 0):

- I should use `COSINE_SIMILARTY` instead of `SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION` because I use discrete preference

  - Don't use threshold, It works not like with param `booleanData=true`
  - I'm not sure that I have to "remap" my natural user, item ids to to surrogate [0...N].

Problem looks like solved. Thank you guys!